# Use generic webhook trigger variables in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-generic-webhook-trigger

I am using the generic webhook plugin to trigger my builds: https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/

In the settings of this plugin it allows you to define variables based on the content of the webhook.  I use this to create variable like $name & $branch.

I can use these variables inside the trigger condition for the build (I use it to check the commit is for the right branch).

What I would really like to do is have access to the variables I define here inside my actual pipeline.

So I would be able to do something like:

```
steps {
        slackSend(channel: "#pipeline", message: 'Starting to build ${branch} for ${name}', botUser: true, color: 'good')
    }
```

How can I get these webhook variables into my build environment variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Guerrilla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/657477/guerrilla) answered this in a comment, but the fix is to use double quotes instead of single quotes as below:

```
steps {
    slackSend(channel: "#pipeline", message: "Starting to build ${branch} for ${name}", botUser: true, color: 'good')
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this - I use a `[key: 'gh_pr_number', value: '$.pull_request.number']` but when I try to `sh"echo $gh_pr_number"`, I get a variable not defined error `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: gh_pr_number for class: groovy.lang.Binding`. My reading of the documentation indicates that `[key:'var_name' ...]` should define a variable in Groovy space accessible directly as `$var_name`, right...?

Comment: Nevermind. For some reason, it started working, and I do not understand why unfortunately. But the behaviour as I understood it is indeed correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
steps {
    slackSend(channel: "#pipeline", message: 'Starting to build ${params.branch} for ${params.name}', botUser: true, color: 'good')
}
```

Comment: Can you try with ${env.branch} and ${env.name}

Comment: I had already tried that.  I don't think the plugin is setting it as an environment variable in build environment, just within scope of plugin execution.

Comment: Ok. This is because i thought ${params.branch} and ${params.name} will work. Anyway, no problem. I will also check if i get some other alternatives.

Comment: actually i just found issue.  I changed single quote to double quote and then it works with $branch